# Canned cubed tomatoes vs crushed

Tags: tomatoes, chili

I have a recipe (for pumpkin turkey chili) which calls for 14 oz can of cubed tomatoes. All I have is either 10 oz cube canned tomatoes or 14 oz crushed tomatoes. Which should I use?  Does it make a difference using the correct quantity but the incorrect type of tomatoes?

Answer (score 4):

In a chili application, the recipe is going to be forgiving.

You will get a little more texture from the cubed (diced) tomatoes assuming that your recipe doesn't then cook them down a considerable time; more absolute quantity of tomato flavor from the crushed simply because you have more of it.  Both should give you good outcomes.

Choose the one that you think you will prefer, and don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't going to matter that much, except the crushed tomatoes will break apart a bit more in to smaller pieces.

Just make sure that the can of tomatoes is not preseasoned, as that might throw off your flavor balance.